# Can Inception-ResNet be inverted layer-by-layer?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, image-generation, residual-networks

It has [already been shown](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/behrmann19a/behrmann19a.pdf) that by using a normalization layer during training, it is possible to [invert a residual network layer-by-layer](https://github.com/jhjacobsen/invertible-resnet).

I wonder how similar [Inception-ResNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07261.pdf) is and whether a similar normalization step could be used to also make them invertible. If inverting it layer-by-layer is possible, it may then be possible to achieve even better reconstructions using a [pixel2style2pixel](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2021/papers/Richardson_Encoding_in_Style_A_StyleGAN_Encoder_for_Image-to-Image_Translation_CVPR_2021_paper.pdf) network which uses feature maps in a [feature pyramid network](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Lin_Feature_Pyramid_Networks_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf) derived from the Inception-ResNet.

If not, would that make [pre-training a seperate network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07261.pdf) the only option?